# How to check whether entered date is in format yyyy/mm/dd?

Tags: r, date, lubridate

An input in my code asks for a date, which I want the user to enter as yyyy/mm/dd. After the date is entered, I want to check whether the date is actually in that format and if not, the user will be asked to enter the date again.

I found a function which should check that here: https://gist.github.com/micstr/69a64fbd0f5635094a53

However, when I added this function to my code and entered a wrong date format ("2016/18/24") the return of this function was not FALSE but TRUE.

Here is the code:

```
library(lubridate)
IsDate <- function(mydate) {
  tryCatch(!is.na(as.Date(mydate, "",tryFormats = "%Y/%m/%d")),  
           error = function(err) {FALSE})  
}

date1<- readline("Enter date (Format: yyyy/mm/dd):")

check <- IsDate(date1)
while(check == FALSE){
  otp_date <- readline("Date in wrong format. Enter again:")
  check <- IsDate(date1)
}
date1<- as.Date(date1)
```

How do I need to adjust my code such that it tackles my problem?

Comment: hi. could you explain a bit more, i.e. why you think the format you entered is "wrong"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use the `chron`-package instead?

```
IsDate <- function(mydate) {
  tryCatch(!is.na(suppressWarnings(chron(mydate, format = "y/m/d"))),  
           error = function(err) {FALSE})  
}

> IsDate("02/02/2016")
[1] FALSE

> IsDate("2016/18/24")
[1] FALSE

> IsDate("2019/10/03")
[1] TRUE
```

Comment: Ok thanks! It works now when I enter a wrong months/day. However, if I enter for example  `02/02/2016` I get `TRUE`, although the format is not YYYY/MM/DD. Can I force the wrongly entered date to be of the correct format or adjust the function such that it does not return `TRUE` in the first place?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Works perfeclty fine now!

Answer (score 1):

Do not use regular expressions.  Use a date library.  My favourite one parse dates (and datetimes) without requiring a format string:

```
R> library(anytime)
R> anydate("2016/18/24")
[1] NA
R> anydate("2016/08/24")
[1] "2016-08-24"
R>
```

So if you get a date back, all is good. If you get `NA` there was an issue.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a vectorized base R function that works with NA and is safe against SQL injection:

```
is_date = function(x, format = NULL) {
  formatted = try(as.Date(x, format), silent = TRUE)
  is_date = as.character(formatted) == x & !is.na(formatted)  # valid and identical to input
  is_date[is.na(x)] = NA  # Insert NA for NA in x
  return(is_date)
}
```

Let's try:

```
> is_date(c("2020-08-11", "2020-13-32", "2020-08-11; DROP * FROM table", NA), format = "%Y-%m-%d")
## TRUE FALSE FALSE    NA
```